# Is it halal to eat vegetables/fruit from an non muslim store/ People of the book store or is it haram?

Tags: halal-haram

So basically I always avoid vegetables/fruit from non muslim stores/ people of the book
because I thought they put chemicals on it that could be haram So im right/ or wrong?